# How to add a protected variable in java

Tags: java, java-7

I need to add a protected variable to the product class file(i have attached the current code of that file) that i have. I need to change the access modifier for the count variable from public to protected. 
How do i do that?! What changes i need to make in the code below to add a protected variable:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Product
{
    private String code;
    private String description;
    private double price;
    public static int count = 0;

    public Product()
    {
        code = "";
        description = "";
        price = 0;
    }

    public void setCode(String code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode(){
        return code;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public String getFormattedPrice()
    {
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return currency.format(price);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Code:        " + code + "\n" +
               "Description: " + description + "\n" +
               "Price:       " + this.getFormattedPrice() + "\n";
    }

    public static int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as you've declared `count` to be public, you can change it to be protected much in the same way just by using the `protected` keyword:

```
protected static int count = 0;
```

Note that this will prevent classes from other packages that do not extend `Product` from accessing `count` directly.  However, they will still be able to obtain its value from the `getCount()` method, as that is public.  If you wish to change that to be protected, you can do so again just by changing the keyword:

```
protected static int getCount()
{
    return count;
}
```

Comment: YES i did the same! :) Thanks. I figured out myself only! So happy! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your variables you have now:

```
private String code;
private String description;
private double price;
public static int count = 0;
```

If you want the count variable to be protected instead of public, it should be:

```
private String code;
private String description;
private double price;
protected static int count = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Mathagan. Why people write bullshit like its your homework. YES IT IS> if you get stuck and you need people's help so what! wow. And you know what I figured that out. It was so simple! :P Stupid me

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Product p=new Product(); 
     Class productClass = p.getClass(); 
     Field f = productClass.getDeclaredField("count"); 
     f.setAccessible(false); //Make the variable non-accessible
  }
```

Comment: I thought he is talking about runtime change...:)